# Python - Tkinter - GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm creating a new application for my current project using Python. This is the first time I use it and it has been a learning experience...

I have a button in my application that calls the `askcolor()` function from Python. Everything works fine the first time but after that, it gives me the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

This is the sequence that I have working in my application:

1. The user click on the `Select Color` button:

   ```
   self.bc_bttn=Button(self, text='Select Color', command=lambda: self.callback())
   ```
2. The function calls the `callback` function and I select the proper color

   ```
   def callback(self):
        (triple, hexstr) = askcolor()
        if triple:
            triple_string = str(triple)
            triple_string2 = re.findall('[0-9, ]',triple_string);
            triple_bkgColor = ''.join(triple_string2)
            print triple_bkgColor
            self.overlayColorValue.set(triple_bkgColor)
   ```
3. `self.overlayColorValue.set(triple_bkgColor)` changes the value of the text field entry so the user will see the correct value on the application
4. I press the `Save` button

   ```
   self.overlayColorValue = self.bc_ent.get()
   body.set('overlay-color', self.overlayColorValue)
   ```
5. My changes are written to the xml file

   ```
   tree.write(CONFIG_XML)
   ```
6. Everything works fine this time but if I want to do the same thing again to change the color. then I have the following error when I click on the `Select Color` button

   ```
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
   ```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting. You should verify the indentation in your code and fix it if needed. Also, try to come up with a more descriptive title. The current one is more like a list of tags, I added the real tags. Press [edit] to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You replaced your `self.overlayColorValue` attribute with the return value of `self.bc_ent.get()`, which is a `str`.

Presumably, before that time, it was a label, and you wanted to call `.set()` on it instead:

```
self.overlayColorValue.set(self.bc_ent.get())
body.set('overlay-color', self.overlayColorValue.get())
```